# How to pass many ids in post__in?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I need to pass many ids to the parameter `post__in` in args. This not work !!! Help me please.

```
foreach ($rows as $obj) {

    $todos .= $obj->ID . ",";

}

$ids = trim(trim($todos), ","); # echo $ids output -------> 613,647

$args = array (
     'post_type' => 'professores',
     'post__in'  => array($ids)    <----- Don't work
);
```

How to do this work?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't concatenate your id values into a comma separate string otherwise you will have to `explode()` by comma delimiter which is pointless, instead, if you are getting IDs from some other business logic as evidenced in your iteration over `$rows`, then build an array of IDs as per the following example:

```
$ids = array();

foreach ($rows as $obj) {
    $ids[] = $obj->ID;
}

$args = array (
     'post_type' => 'professores',
     'post__in'  => $ids
);
```

Comment: Very very fantastic !!!!

Comment: @Adam, I am getting the same issue but I have $ids=1,2 . do I need to use explode?

Comment: @NarenVerma for reference, yes, the `post__in` or `post__not_in` parameters must take an array of post IDs, so if you have a string `'$ids= 1,2,3,4,5'`, you will need to explode by the appropriate delimiter to obtain an array of integers. You should also map over the array to get the `intval` of the ID, as they will be cast to strings on first exploding the variable... e.g. `array_map( 'intval', explode(',', '1,2,3') )`